# How to prevent XPath/XML injection in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, code-injection

How can I prevent XPATH injection in the .NET Framework?

We were previously using string concatenation to build XPATH statements, but found that end users could execute some arbitrary XPATH. For example:

```
string queryValue = "pages[@url='" + USER_INPUT_VALUE + "']";
node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(queryValue);
```

Would it be sufficient to strip out single and double quotes from input strings?

Or, does the .NET framework support parameterized XPATH queries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The main idea in preventing an XPath injection is to pre-compile the XPath expression you want to use and to allow variables (parameters) in it, which during the evaluation process will be substituted by user-entered values**.

**In .NET**:

1. Have your XPath expresion pre-compiled with **[XPathExpression.Compile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163317.aspx)**.
2. Use the **[XPathExpression.SetContext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs084hw.aspx) Method** to specify as context an **[XsltContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.aspx)** object that resolves some specific variables to the user-entered values.

You can read more about how to evaluate an XPath expression that contains variables **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715.aspx)**.

This text contains good and complete examples.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly typed parameters are available if you use a full-blown [XsltTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882.aspx).

Comment: In my case, I am just trying to search for a node in an XML file. So XSLT is overkill.

Comment: Strongly typed parameters are possible not only using an XSLT transformation -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized XPath is possible if you use Saxon as your XPath processor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strongly typed parameters you could decrease the options for a user. Why give them full control if you do not want that?

Provide the user with a couple of option to select from and then create the query.

Allowing the user to enter any string is asking for trouble or a lot of work.

Comment: What you're suggesting sounds like sanitizing input. Can you provide the set of characters which must be filtered for XPATH?

Comment: @frankadelic: You don't need "a set of characters" at all. The way to protect from an XPath injection is to use a pre-compiled XPath expressions that contains variables. See my answer for explanation and links to the relevant .NET documentation.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Do not allow string input. Give some option buttons and check boxes and hard code the queries.

Comment: Thanks, however, in my use case I cannot reduce the input choice to a set of options. If that were the case, I would use a whitelist approach.