# Xpath using an attribute as a variable in an xml file where there is a namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

If we have this xml file and I want to use the attribute Author as a variable to get the title

```
<bookstore>
 <book author="Tommy">
   <title>Emma</title>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

I know that I must write this

```
string au = "Tommy";
string query = String.Format("//bookstore/book[@author={0}]/title", au);
```

If we also have this example and I want to get the title

```
<bk:bookstore xmlns:bk="http://www.example.com/">
  <book author="Tommy">
    <title>Emma</title>
  </book>
</bk:bookstore>
```

I know that I must write this

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "http://www.test.com/");
XmlNodeList elements0 = xml.SelectNodes("//bk:bookstore/book/title", nsmgr);
```

But I don't know what to do if I have the second example and I also want to use the attribute Author as a variable. I have tried this

```
string au = "Tommy";
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "http://www.test.com/");
XmlNodeList elements0 = xml.SelectNodes("//bk:bookstore/book[@author={0}]/title", au, nsmgr);
```

or this

```
XmlNodeList elements0 = xml.SelectNodes("//bk:bookstore/book[@author={0}]/title", nsmgr, au);
```

or this

```
XmlNodeList elements0 = xml.SelectNodes("//bk:bookstore/book[@author={1}]/title", nsmgr, au);
```

but it doesn't work.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Your XML has the namespace `http://www.example.com/`, but you're using `http://www.test.com/` in your namespace manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things up.

First build a path. Then use it. The namespace manager only matters for the second step.

```cs
string au = "Tommy";
string path = String.Format("//bk:bookstore/book[@author = '{0}']/title", au);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "http://www.test.com/");

XmlNodeList elements0 = xml.SelectNodes(path, nsmgr);
```

Note the single quotes in the path.

---

Also note that this *will* break when there is a single quote in the input string (`au`). This can be a source of random run-time errors in the best case and attack vector for XPath injection in the worst case. Which means you *must* handle that situation.

Your options to work around this issue are:

1. Explicitly forbid single quotes in the input and additionally use `au.Replace("'", "")` when building the path. This is probably not suitable for person names.
2. Build a more complex path that allows single quotes. This isn't trivial since XPath does not have an escaping mechanism for strings.
3. [Use a more advanced way of defining an XPath query.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393690/18771)

For option 2, assuming the author `"O'Reilly"`, the path would need to look like this:

```
//bk:bookstore/book[@author = concat('O', "'", 'Reilly')]/title
```

because the expression `concat('O', "'", 'Reilly')` produces the string `"O'Reilly"` in the XPath engine. Using `concat()` in this manner is the only way to embed delimiting quotes into XPath strings.

This function produces such an expression:

```cs
public static string XPathEscape(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return "''";

    if (input.Contains("'"))
    {
        string[] parts = input.Split("'".ToCharArray());
        return String.Format("concat('{0}')", String.Join(@"', ""'"", '", parts));
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Format("'{0}'", input);
    }
}
```

use it as follows:

```cs
string au = "O'Reilly";
string path = String.Format("//bk:bookstore/book[@author = {0}]/title", XPathEscape(au));
```

Note that there are no single quotes in the path this time.