# C#, Trying to add child node to node with specific attribute

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath

I am attempting to create a tool from WPF that creates a simple XML document by inputting data into a text box, then clicking a button to enter that data into the XML document. Other than the root element, I will have a step element with a child sub step element such as this:

```
<root>
<step id="1">
    <P>some instructions</p>
    <step id="1.1">
        <p>some additional instructions</p>
    </step>
</step>
<step id="2">
    <p>second set of instructions</p>
    <step id="2.1">
        <p>additional instructions for step 2</p>
    </step>
</step>
```

I have been able to add the parent steps, however all of my sub steps  fall under the first parent step:

```
<root>
<step id="1">
  <step id="1.1">
  <step id="2.1">
  <step id="3.1">
<step id="2">
<step id="3">
```

I am trying to use XPath to insert my sub steps into the proper parent-steps.  However I am receiving the error:
"XAttribute does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument type 'XAttribute' could be found."

I have searched extensively and am unable to come up with a solution, hopefully this makes sense and someone could give me a hand.  Thank you in advance.  Here is my code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace XMLwpfTest1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
           new XElement("Content",
           new XElement("Title", "DM Title"))
          );

        string par = "par-";

        int counter = 1;
        int counter2 = 1;
        string stepNumber = "";



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            doc.Element("Content").Add(
                new XElement("proceduralStep",
                new XAttribute("id", par + counter.ToString("D4")),
                new XElement("para",
            dataBox.Text)));
            stepNumber = par + counter.ToString("D4");
            counter += 1;
            dataBox.Clear();
            counter2 = 1;
        }


        private void createSubStep_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var addStep = doc.XPathSelectElement("Content/proceduralStep").Attribute(stepNumber);


            addStep.add(
            new XElement("proceduralStep",
            new XAttribute("id", stepNumber + "-" + counter2.ToString("D4")),
            new XElement("para",
        subDataBox.Text)));
            counter2 += 1;
            subDataBox.Clear();
        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            doc.Save(fileName.Text + ".xml");
            savedLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the full xml file? Where do Content/proceduralStep and content come from? I don't see them in the xml

Comment: The XML I put in the question is only the structure I was looking for.  Those aren't the actual tag names.  i should have put the actual tag names I am using.  Sorry for the confusion.  The <Content> and <proceduralStep> are the elements that will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes at this line:

```
var addStep = doc.XPathSelectElement("Content/proceduralStep").Attribute(stepNumber);
```

It looks like you want to select the `<proceduralStep>` whose `id` attribute has value `stepNumber`.  To do this with XPath, you need to use the syntax `[@attributeName='attributeValue']`, i.e.:

```
var addStep = doc.XPathSelectElement(string.Format("Content/proceduralStep[@id='{0}']", stepNumber));
```

Note that, if `stepNumber` were a *user-entered string*, you would need to be careful to prevent [XPath injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection), for instance by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381689/how-to-prevent-xpath-xml-injection-in-net).

Alternatively, you could do this using by appending a [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) expression:

```
var addStep = doc.XPathSelectElements("Content/proceduralStep")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == stepNumber)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

XPath injection is not an issue with this approach.

(The method you are currently calling, [`XElement.Attribute(XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx), returns the *attribute* with the specified name, which you do not want.)

Then `add()` needs to be correctly capitalized as [`XElement.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add.aspx):

```
addStep.Add(
new XElement("proceduralStep",
new XAttribute("id", stepNumber + "-" + counter2.ToString("D4")),
new XElement("para", subDataBox.Text)));
```